# How do I prepare for another application?

Tags: application, university, europe

I applied to a Master degree in Computer Science, however my application was not accepted. The university that I applied to is one of the top ranked my field and I do intend to apply the following year.

In bachelor I completed my degree as an average student with a 14 grade (out of 20) within 5 years, when the course duration is just 3. This is obviously a thing that I can no longer cope for, nor one that I feel guilty of. I will also take less priority than the students that take the bachelor in that same country.

Those are the reasons I believe there should be a lot of candidates that take preference over me, however I can still try by improving my TOEFL test. Last I time I tried I took 76 out of 120, while I stated the score I took on this exam I thought it would be best to not include the certificate of the exam, so it wouldn't be taken into account.

The application to this university was taken into two phases and I preferred to get my application earlier on the 1st phase so I could get a small advantage on the time (Although I am not sure if they give preference to applicants from the 1st phase).

I can also appeal about the decision taken, I would like to know **why** exactly I didn't get chosen over the last 10 applicants, so I could improve my application and increase the chances of being chosen.

How can I prepare for my next application? (How) Should I appeal to the decision  taken?

Comment: TOEFL score is something which generally does not matter other than you just have to cross that barrier.

Comment: Appeals are only for situations when misconduct is suspected.  Do not bother filing one.  Did you consider other universities?  Did you ask the university what sort of applicants they are looking for?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I did not apply for other universities this year and I currently don't have enough conditions (€) to apply to other universities that I considered. I just asked that and they told me that they are not able to give me more information on how the candidates are assessed.